# Running multiple Winedt processes on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows, winedt

Is it possible to run multiple versions of Winedt, Build: 20100317  (v. 6.0) on Windows 7 x64 system to edit multiple projects?

Comment: WinEdt is a single-window application: I doubt you can run more than one copy at once, independent of the particular version of Windows you use.

Comment: @Joseph: I don't use Windows very often so I could be wrong, but isn't that the typical use case for single window applications?

Comment: @TH. Exactly correct, hence me wondering about the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start a second instance with the command line switches -C or -c. E.g.

```
winedt -C="second winedt"
```

The help about "Command Line Switches" contains also examples how to associate a project or a special ini file to such a second instance.

Comment: is "second winedt" kind of file name?
when i tried -C option, i cannot open new instance, and an popup window shows that the file named "second winedt" cannot be found, but when i use -c "second winedt", i can open new instances, but there is still popup window telling that file cannot be found? what i should do so that there is no popup window then?

Comment: @hugemeow "second winedt" is the name which you will see at the top of the application window (and in the button on the taskbar). I just tested the command again with winedt 7 and it works fine, but naturally winedt itself must be found so if it is not in your PATH you will have to use something like `C:\programme\.....\WinEdt.exe -C="second winedt"`.